# Avoid making copies with vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, stl, vector

I want to be able to have a vector of vectors of some type such as:

```
vector<vector<MyStruct> > vecOfVec;
```

I then create a vector of MyStruct, and populate it.

```
vector<MyStruct> someStructs;
// Populate it with data
```

Then finally add someStructs to vecOfVec;

```
vecOfVec.push_back(someStructs);
```

What I want to do is avoid having the copy constructor calls when pushing the vector.  I know this can be accomplished by using a vector of pointers, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

One strategy I've thought of seems to work, but I don't know if I'm over-engineering this problem.

```
// Push back an empty vector
vecOfVec.push_back(vector<MyStruct>());

// Swap the empty with the filled vector (constant time)
vecOfVec.back().swap(someStructs);
```

This seems like it would add my vector without having to do any copies, but this seems like something a compiler would already be doing during optimization.

Do you think this is a good strategy?

**Edit:** Simplified my swap statement due to some suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you want to just store the pointers?

Comment: Small nitpick: you could just call vecOfVec.back().swap(someStructs).

Comment: Move your code into a `move` function, and I'd call it good, and it looks somewhat similar to C++0x: `template <typename Cont> void move(Cont& pContainer, typename Cont::value_type& pValue){ pContainer.push_back(typename Cont::value_type()); pContainer.back().swap(pValue);}` This function moves data into the back of a container via swap. Untested :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The swap trick is as good as it gets with C++03. In C++0x, you'll be able to use the vector's move constructor via `std::move` to achieve the same thing in a more obvious way.

Another option is to not create a separate `vector<MyStruct>`, but instead have the code that creates it accept it a a `vector<MyStruct>&` argument, and operate on it. Then, you add a new empty element to your outer `vector<vector<MyStruct>>`, and pass a reference to the code that will fill it.

Comment: Pavel,

That might be seen as a problem, because in order to save performance (copy) you change the semantics of your algorithm.

Suddenly, just because it's a large dataset you are going to avoid return-value semantics. IMHO, this is contrary to object-oriented programming principles.

Comment: C++ is not a pure OO language for a reason, and pragmaticism is a big part of it. Furthermore, using byref over return values is a long-standing performance-improving technique, and there's nothing wrong with it, for those cases where it yields a clear improvement. I agree that return style is more natural, but then `swap` trick isn't (and you've got to use one or another to get decent perf out of this).

Answer (score 4):

> I know this can be accomplished by
>   using a vector of pointers, but I'd
>   like to avoid that if possible.

Why?

That would be the most intuitive/readable/maintainable solution and would be much better than any weird hacks anyone comes up with (such as the swap you show).

Comment: In many cases, I do in fact use vectors of pointers.  But due to part of the issue I'm currently working, I want to avoid it.  I'd rather pose a simple example instead of giving paragraphs of explanation that I doubt you'd be interested in reading.  On another note, what I'm doing is far from being some kind of hack.

Comment: These don't look like 'weird hacks' to me.

Comment: I consider them hacks because vectors weren't meant to be used this way and code such as this is un-intuitive. "Weird" might have been a strong adjective.

Answer (score 3):

Tim,

There's a common pattern to solve this. This is called **smart pointers**, and the best one to use is boost::shared_ptr.

Then, never pass vector by value or store it. Instead, store boost::shared_ptr >. You don't need to care about allocations/deallocations (when the containing vector is destroyed, so will be the others, just as in your code), and you can access the inner members almost the same way. The copy is, however, avoided by means of the smart pointer object's *reference counting* mechanism.

Let me show you how.

```
using boost::shared_ptr;
vector<shared_ptr<vector<MyStruct> > vecOfVecs;
shared_ptr<vector<MyStruct> > someStructs(new vector<MyStruct>);
// fill in the vector MyStructs
MyStructs->push_back(some struct.... as you usually do).  
//...
vecOfVecs.push_back(someStructs); // Look! No copy!
```

If you do not already use boost::shared_ptr, I recommend downloading it from boost.org rather than implementing your own. It is really irreplaceable tool, soon to be in the C++ standard library.

Comment: P.S. This is also the proper way to return vector out of a function, to avoid reference-parameter-upload semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do something like vect.push_back(vector<MyStruct>()); and do vect.back().push_back(MyStruct()); or use smart pointers and have a vector of smart pointers to vector<MyStruct>

Answer (score 0):

I think the swap idea is already fine, but can be written much easier:

```
vecOfVec.push_back(vector<MyStruct>());
vecOfVec.back().swap(someStructs);
```